# Using !DOCTYPE html on coldfusion pages - IE9 rendering

Tags: html, internet-explorer, coldfusion, internet-explorer-9, doctype

What is the best way to have ie9 render a  < !DOCTYPE html > .cfm page in standards mode rather than quirks?

I've been having this issue for a while and suspiciously, only on coldfusion sites!  I just got the 'bright' idea of changing the file extension to .html and BAM! the pages rendered out perfectly in standards mode.

Needless to say, this was the first collection of pages that I didn't have to develop in a test environment, since all they use are html5, css, jquery/javascript which gave me the idea of changing the filename extension to html.

Can anyone share how they get around this (without changing the filename extension)?  I would be very much indebted to you!

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you're setting the correct [content type](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c82.html) for the page:

```
<cfcontent type="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Also check that ColdFusion isn't putting anything before the `DOCTYPE` declaration.

Finally, be aware that IE will render intranet pages in quirks mode by default in a number of situations even when [you've done everything right](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: To go along with what Robert said about ColdFusion putting anything before the DOCTYPE declaration, if you have not done so, you should turn on 'white space management' in the ColdFusion Administrator. Its under Server Settings -> Settings.

Comment: Thank you both Scott and Robert for your answers.  I will definitely follow up on what you've written and those two links are bookmarked.